# Fixing the pointcut definition error while defining an aspect for tracing the RabbitMQ send

Tags: aspectj, spring-aop, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit, opentracing

The opentracing instrumentation for spring-rabbitmq doesn't have an aspect defined for tracing the `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate#send`. Here is the link of the code: [RabbitMqSendTracingAspect.java](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-rabbitmq/blob/master/opentracing-spring-rabbitmq/src/main/java/io/opentracing/contrib/spring/rabbitmq/RabbitMqSendTracingAspect.java)

I tried implementing it and got some serious errors while defining a pointcut.

Here is my code for the same:

```java
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class AmqpSendTracingAspect {
    private final Tracer tracer;

    public AmqpSendTracingAspect(Tracer tracer) {
        this.tracer = tracer;
    }

    @Around(value = "execution(* org.springframework.amqp.core.AmqpTemplate.send(..)) " +
            "&& args(exchange,routingKey, message)", 
            argNames = "pjp,exchange,routingKey,message")
    public Object traceAmqpSend(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, 
        String exchange, String routingKey, Message message) throws Throwable {

        final Object[] args = pjp.getArgs();

        System.out.println("Aspect RUnning");

        final MessageProperties messageProperties = message.getMessageProperties();

        Scope scope = AmqpTracingUtils.buildSendSpan(tracer, messageProperties);
        tracer.inject(
                scope.span().context(),
                Format.Builtin.TEXT_MAP,
                new AmqpInjectAdapter(messageProperties));

        AmqpSpanDecorator spanDecorator = new AmqpSpanDecorator();
        spanDecorator.onSend(messageProperties, exchange, routingKey, scope.span());

        args[2] = message;

        try {
            return pjp.proceed(args);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            spanDecorator.onError(ex, scope.span());
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            scope.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following errors from `CglibAopProxy` framework even when I annotated with `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = false)`

```
Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.start()] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!

Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.stop()] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
```

Please help me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an error. the code producing that message is like this:

```
if (implementsInterface(method, ifcs)) {
                        logger.info("Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [" + method + "] because " +
                                "it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!");
                    }
```

So, it is an `info` and it fully doesn't stop your application to work afterward. Just a pointer that `RabbitTemplate.start()` method is not going to be proxied, which definitely should not be. So, you are good so far.

I think since you use Spring Cloud, you are not able to override the AOP config with that `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` therefore it always uses `CglibAopProxy`.

I would just ignore that `info`. Would be better do not such a logging level for framework categories.